# Getting desperate with Python file importing

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I searched for dozen different tutorials and currently i am struggling with importing a file from different subdirectory. I am using python3.
the folders look like this:

```
app
|-gui/
|   |-interface.py
|-src/
|   |-main.py
|-utils/
|   |-var.py
```

In main.py i am trying do import var.py with a two classes. This way: import utils.var.
Horewer its the classic error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'utils'.
I tried all different combinations app.utils.var, var, utils, app.utils, nothing seems to work. Even tried relative imports like ..utils.var etc.
What seems to be the problem???

Comment: [Also Relevant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132789/relative-imports-for-the-billionth-time)

Comment: Making cosmetic edits to closed questions is problematic. If the duplicate solved your problem, we are done. If not, your next edit should explain why this isn't a duplicate.

Comment: get the main.py out of the `src` folder. then just use `import gui.interface` or `import utils.var` that should work